# Replace First Occurrence Only of Pipe Character in String

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, sed, gnu-sed

I need to remove an extra pipe character at the end of header row of a pipe delimited csv file with sed.  The literal string that I am trying to find is COLNAME|

Working on a GCP Windows server.  The command I am trying to use:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" sed  '0,/COLNAME"|"/s//COLNAME/' FILENAME

returns the output...
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command

I'm new to sed and have been playing around with the s command for a while but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: So, you want to find and replace `COLNAME"|"` with `COLNAME` in some file, right?

Comment: well the literal string that I want to replace is COLNAME|  the " double quotes are around the pipe in the command I'm trying to run as I read that special characters need to be surrounded with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `COLNAME|` with `COLNAME"|"` in Windows, using the GNU `sed`, you can use

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME|/COLNAME"^""|"^""/g"
```

Here, `COLNAME|` matches `COLNAME|` and `COLNAME"^""|"^""` forms the literal `COLNAME"|"` replacement since `COLNAME"` ends the quoted string, `^"` appends a literal `"` char to the sed command, `"|"` appends a `|` char to the sed command and then `^"` appends another literal `"` to the sed command, and the next `"` starts the finishing part. The `g` flag makes it match and replace all occurrences.

If you want to replace `COLNAME"|"` with `COLNAME` in Windows, using the GNU `sed`, you can do that with

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME"^""|"^""/COLNAME/g" FILENAME
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME\x22|\x22/COLNAME/g" FILENAME
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME\d34|\d34/COLNAME/g" FILENAME
```

Mind that you need to enclose the substitution command with double quotes and to match a double quote, you can't simply use a `"` or a `\"`, you can match it with an escaped `^"`, or with `\x22`, a hex reprentation of the char, or `\d34`.

Note that in `"s/COLNAME"^""|"^""/COLNAME/g"`, the sed command is built in the following way:

1. `"s/COLNAME"` sets the beginning
2. `^"` appends a literal `"` char to the sed command
3. `"|"` - adds `|` pipe char
4. `^"` - adds another `"`
5. `"/COLNAME/g"` - finishes off the sed command with the replacement and the global modifier/flag.

Comment: the literal string that I want to replace is COLNAME| 
the double quotes are around the pipe in the command I'm trying to run as I read that special characters need to be surrounded with double quotes

Comment: @BrianP_TRHC So, you want to replace `COLNAME|` with `COLNAME"|"`? Then use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME|/COLNAME"^""|"^""/g" FILENAME`

Comment: @BrianP_TRHC See the updated answer, does it work now?

Comment: No, the literal string that I want to replace is COLNAME| with COLNAME

Comment: @BrianP_TRHC So, there is no issue at all then, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "s/COLNAME|/COLNAME/g" FILENAME` works fine.

Comment: the only issue with that syntax is the time it takes to scan the entire file; this will be used on files >500GB so I would prefer to only find/replace the first occurrence of COLNAME| with COLNAME.  Or, if it's easier, just go the end of the first line and delete the pipe, but I am not familiar enough with scripting to accomplish that.

Comment: Deleting the pipe on the first line at its end is just `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "1!b;s/|$//" FILENAME`

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "1!b;s/|$//" FILENAME did not seem to work. COLNAME| still remained at the end of the header row upon completion.  Also, it still scanned the entire file; this will be used in automation to process files >500 GB daily so scanning the full file will not be sufficient for the task I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BrianP_TRHC That is probably due to CRLF endings, you might just try `sed "s/\r//g"` before. Or, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "1!b;s/|[[:space:]]*$//" FILENAME` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" "1!b;s/|\r*$//" FILENAME`